# REST API in Windows Azure

Tags: php, rest, azure-storage

I am trying to connect to Windows Azure REST API, but always get issue like this:

```
The MAC signature found in the HTTP request '...' is not the same as any computed signature.
```

I can't get correct signature. I also tried on Objective-C and with different methods of Windows Azure REST API, but always get the same error. There are full listing on PHP:

```
function send_request($url, $headers)
{
    if ($curl = curl_init())
    {
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        return curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
    }
    return false;
}

function encode_string_to_sign($string_to_sign, $key)
{
    $hash = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $key, true);
    $signature = base64_encode($hash);

    return $signature;
}

header("Content-Type: application/xhtml+xml");

// GET Container Metadata
$url = "http://snip.blob.core.windows.net/elements?restype=container&comp=metadata";
$access_key_1 = "...";
$access_key_2 = "...";

$current_date = "Thu, 28 Feb 2013 21:10:00 GMT";

$canonicalized_headers = "x-ms-date:$current_date\nx-ms-version:2009-09-19";
$canonicalized_resource = "/snip/elements\ncomp:metadata\nrestype:container";
$string_to_sign = "GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" . $canonicalized_headers . "\n" . $canonicalized_resource;

$signature = utf8_encode(encode_string_to_sign($string_to_sign, $access_key_1));
$headers = array("Authorization: SharedKey snip:" . $signature, "x-ms-date: " . $current_date, "x-ms-version: 2009-09-19");

echo send_request($url, $headers);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PHP, why not using Windows Azure PHP SDK to do it? https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php

which had been well tested against real server.

Comment: There are some methods that aren't supported with the sdk. What's the best way to implement these?

Comment: What specific API r u talking about, msft would love u to contribute to this SDK.

Comment: I'm new to azure, Is azure php sdk available all features that available from REST Api.

Comment: I think so, at least mostly